# Repairing a torn-off PCB pad

Tags: pcb, soldering

I'm a soldering beginner and messed up my first attempt to repair something.

The picture shows a pad I tore off while desoldering a component (the poor state of the other pad is also my fault). Does it look like something that could be salvaged by someone more experienced?

[image: Picture of torn-off pad]

Edit: The reverse side looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What does the pad look like on the other side of the board?

Comment: I've added a picture of the other side to the question. The pad looks undamaged.

Comment: Did the pad connect to that ground plane? That would be easy to bridge. Otherwise you’ll need to run a bodge wire out to the net it used to connect to

Comment: Clean the brown stains with a ear cotton and alcohol and remove the leftover solder with solder suck wire/desoldering braid.

Comment: First impression is the signal layers are in the inner layers. Could be positive.

Comment: @Bryan There aren't any visible traces connecting to the component, so I'm not sure. Incidentally it was capacitor that had gone bad.

Comment: @worst_cathedral try beeping the remaining bits out to other things that look like a ground on that board. It could be that losing the backside pad isn’t as bad as it looks and you can just slap a new cap in and hide your sins.

Comment: @RemyHx I'll definitely do that, thanks. What would you suggest if the signal layers are inner layers? (I'm pretty sure it doesn't connect to anything on the surface).

Comment: @Bryan Thank you for the ray of light, though think I'd be out my depth poking around on this board (pictures: [1](https://web.archive.org/web/20160731053641/http://diy.sickmods.net/images/xbox_1_6_top_clean.jpg) [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20160731050926/http://diy.sickmods.net/images/xbox_1_6_bottom_clean.jpg) ). If there's no easy fix I'll seek out someone who knows what they're doing.

Comment: _"The picture shows a pad I tore off"_ - I don't see a torn off pad. Please clean the area and show us a photo so we can see where the pad was torn off from.

Comment: @worst_cathedral I want to see the cleared up area. I think it is just ok, but to be sure. Like Bruce also suggests.